# Não consigo gerar esse segundo vetor

Tags: java, java-8

Escreva um programa que carregue um vetor com 10 números inteiros e o ordene em ordem crescente, usando o método bubble sort.

O programa deve gerar um segundo vetor sem os números repetidos.

```
package com.bubble.sort;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bubble_sort {
    private static Scanner teclado;

    public static void main(String args []) {
        int vet1[] = new int [10];
        int vet2[] = new int [10];
        int n, i, aux,troca;

        teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Carregando os números do vetor:
        for(i=0;i<=9;i++) {

            System.out.print("Digite "+(i+1)+"º número do vetor:");
            vet1[i]= teclado.nextInt();
            vet2[i] = vet1[i];
        }
        n = 1;
        troca = 1;
        while (n <= 10 && troca == 1) {

            troca = 0;
            for(i=0;i<=8;i++) {

                if(vet1[i] > vet1[i+1]) {

                    troca = 1;
                    aux = vet1[i];
                    vet1[i] = vet1[i+1];
                    vet1[i+1] = aux;

                }

            }
            n = n + 1;
        }

        for(i=0;i<=9;i++) {
            System.out.print("["+vet1[i]+"]");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lembrando das posições restantes do array que não são usadas, e devem ser ignoradas na hora de mostrar o vetor.

```
int valorAnterior =  vet1[0];
int contatodor = 0;
for(i=1;i<=9;i++) {
  if(valorAnterior != vet1[i]){
    vet2[contatodor] = vet1[i];
    valorAnterior = vet1[i];
    contatodor++;
  }
}
```

Código completo:

```
package com.bubble.sort;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bubble_sort {
    private static Scanner teclado;

    public static void main(String args []) {
        int vet1[] = new int [10];
        int vet2[] = new int [10];
        int n, i, aux,troca;

        teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Carregando os números do vetor:
        for(i=0;i<=9;i++) {

            System.out.print("Digite "+(i+1)+"º número do vetor:");
            vet1[i]= teclado.nextInt();
            vet2[i] = vet1[i];
        }
        n = 1;
        troca = 1;
        while (n <= 10 && troca == 1) {

            troca = 0;
            for(i=0;i<=8;i++) {

                if(vet1[i] > vet1[i+1]) {

                    troca = 1;
                    aux = vet1[i];
                    vet1[i] = vet1[i+1];
                    vet1[i+1] = aux;

                }

            }
            n = n + 1;
        }

        for(i=0;i<=9;i++) {
            System.out.print("["+vet1[i]+"]");
        }

        int valorAnterior =  vet1[0];
        vet2[0] =  vet1[0];
        int contatodor = 1;
        for(i=1;i<=9;i++) {
          if(valorAnterior != vet1[i]){
            vet2[contatodor] = vet1[i];
            valorAnterior = vet1[i];
            contatodor++;
          }
        }

        for(i=0;i<contatodor;i++) {
            System.out.print("["+vet2[i]+"]");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Está ficando o mesmo vetor.

Comment: O segundo verto?

Comment: Poderia fazer o código completo?

Comment: Código completo postado.

Comment: Não tem como tirar os 0 na posição repetida não né?

Comment: fiz a alteração, agora não vai mostrar os valores 0

Comment: E está perdendo o primeiro valor sempre!

Comment: Cara fiz uma correção, agora esta pegando o primeiro valor. @Kuriôzu

Comment: No meu está do mesmo jeito.

Comment: A modificação foi bem pequena, você pegou o código novo?

Comment: sim, mas continua não aparecendo o 1º valor do 2 vetor gerado.

Comment: Tenta agora, por favor.

Comment: Agora ta aparecendo o primeiro, porém está aparecendo um número apos os numeros do vetor:
EX.:
[1],[2],[1]

Comment: Pronto amigo, desculpe este tanto de alteração é porque estou no serviço e não tenho uma ide aqui, mas acredito que agora vai funcionar 100%. @Kuriôzu

Comment: 100%, cara ajudou bastante.

Comment: Marcar a resposta como respondida, por favor.